# Delete Records (compaction + tombstone) while using partial key for partitioning

Tags: apache-kafka

We have the following requirements:

1. We need to be able to delete records immediately (best effort) after reading them from a topic due to data privacy requirements
2. We need to keep strict ordering from producer to the consumer for a given (functional) key
3. We need to allow multiple records per key

As we understand we can achieve 1) by using compaction, and overriding records by key with tombstones if they should be deleted. The problem we face is that we have multiple records per key, so using compaction wouldn't work out of the box, since newer records for the same key would override older ones.

Our idea is to use a custom partitioning strategy with a composite key, where the full key is unique (used for tombstones), but part of the key is shared (like a grouping key, used for partitioning).

Question: Is there already a way to do this without implementing a custom strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning does not affect compaction. The full key will always be used.

If you want to allow multiple records, you can use arrays in the values, or aggregate in Kafka Streams to do the same before compaction occurs.

Also keep in mind that only closed segments are compacted, and default segment size is 1GB. Therefore, you might not get data immediately deleted, as you're expecting. It's not recommended to enforce very small segments to invoke frequent compaction as it'll negatively affect the CPU/IO of the cluster.

Comment: `Partitioning does not affect compaction. The full key will always be used.`
This should be fine, because we want to use the full key to delete, but only part of the key for partitioning. Think of the key consisting of a `group` and a unique identifier. We'd use the touple (group, uid) for deletion, but want to partition by group. Would that be feasible?

`Therefore, you might not get data immediately deleted, as you're expecting.`
Thanks for the feedback, we were not aware of that.

Comment: You can use partial keys for partitioning, or even the value. You just need to override the producer partitioner class